# How import csv file into mysql /var/lib/mysql-files/

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import

I need to import csv file into mysql:
first I tried:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/MJ/Desktop/nysgi1.csv' INTO TABLE gift FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (giftid,date,udate,vamount);
```

errors:

```
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

And I then followed some instruction to successfully set local_infile ON ,and then I restarted mysql by using `service mysql restart`.However it not works,still the same error.

Then I tried to use directly:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/MJ/Desktop/nysgi1.csv' INTO TABLE gift FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (giftid,date,udate,vamount);
```

errors:

```
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

So I use:

```
SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv;
```

and find out the directory is:

```
/var/lib/mysql-files/
```

My question is how to import the csv file to  /var/lib/mysql-files/ using command line.

Thanks!

Comment: Imported file MUST be placed into `@@secure_file_priv` directory. And if you use LOCAL then the path MUST be accessible by MySQL, with specified path strictly. I.e. while typing `cd C:/Users/MJ/Desktop` on server console under MySQL account you must successfully access this directory. Share this folder, mount on SQL server, then use mounted path in the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are having exactly the same problem i have,
please use scp command to place your csv file into linux directory.